# spring mvc(rest) with angular2 causing 302 moved temporarily

Tags: angular, spring-security, spring-rest

We have simple spring mvc(rest), security and Angular2 app which is deployed in weblogic 12.1.2 Everything is packaged as single war file including dist folder of angular2 app. When app launched by index.html, it is requesting multiple Angular2 generated js files.

Randomly we are getting  302 moved temporarily status code on this request and that causing app to not launched successfully.

Does anyone know what might be causing this error? Or to be specific how should be handle 302 on server side if it has to be?

Comment: It might be anything. Your description lacks details that could narrow down possibilities - have you checked Weblogic logs, do you have some special servlet filters, where does it redirect with HTTP 302, have you tried to turn off Spring Security and so.

Answer (score -1):

It turned out to be LB was not using proper sticky session.